# error integrating zend with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, zend-framework, generator, barcode

i want to generate barcode image using codeigniter for the first time.
im using this library from this url :
https://github.com/desta88/Codeigniter-Barcode-Generator-Zend-Library

i follow all the instructions. but i got error. it told me that zend lib doesnt exist.

> Non-existent class: Zend

here is my library folder structure :
application
- libraries
  - zend.php
  - zend (folder)
    - barcode (folder)
    - barcode.php
    - exeception.php
    - loader.php
    - validate.php

here is my controller :

```
public function set_barcode($code) {
    //load library
    $this->load->library('zend');
    //load in folder Zend
    $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
    //generate barcode
    Zend_Barcode::render('code128', 'image', array('text'=>$code), array());
}
```

many thanks in advance.

ps :
im using codeigniter v 3.05
zend framework v 2.49

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The file Zend.php in application/libraries declares the class like this.

```
class CI_Zend {
```

Change it to

```
class Zend {
```